# How to get session cookies from response using Ext.Ajax.request ExtJS 6.2

Tags: session, cookies, extjs, httpresponse

I am trying to log in to a service using Ext.Ajax.request (ExtJS Version 6.2) by sending user id and password. A session cookie .ASPXAUTH is returned back in the response. I want to know about a way to get this cookie value, store it at client side and use it for further Ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "cookie" is returned in the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) HTTP response header, you don't need any additional steps to set it or "store it at the client side". As for the getting its value part, you can use the [`Ext.util.Cookies.get("cookieName")`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.util.Cookies.html#method-get) method.

Comment: Once authenticated, I need the session cookie to be used for further calls to the service.I suppose further calls made using ajax are independent of the earlier call made for authentication.

Comment: After the cookie is returned and set, every following request will include the cookie.